# Render output from markdown file inside .rst file

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using `Sphinx` for documenting a Python project and would like to have content from an existing `.md` file display inside of a `.rst` file.
( I have already set up my `conf.py` to allow for markdown).

For example, I have a file called `tutorial.md`. I also have a `.rst` file as follows:

```
ml
==

w2v
^^^

.. automodule:: package.ml.w2v
:members:
```

I would like be able to include a link to `tutorial.md` as follows, such that the content of `tutorial.md` will display in the file upon rendering. This can be achieved with the following:

```
ml
==

Tutorial
--------
.. include:: ../tutorial.md

w2v
^^^

.. automodule:: package.ml.w2v
:members:
```

However, the resulting content looks bad, as it doesn't render the markdown as markdown.

I realize I can avoid this issue by writing the entire documentation as `.md`, but this exercise has left me with the following question:

**Is it possible to have `.md` content render as markdown, *inside* of an `.rst` file?**

Comment: Although the rendered content looks bad, and it doesn't render as markdown, what *does* it render as? A little more information would be helpful. Are there any error or warning messages?

Comment: Also did you install and configure a Sphinx bridge, such as the Python package [recommonmark](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markdown.html)? There are also many flavors of markdown.

Comment: IIRC, no it's not possible. Docutils (the rst parser) has no knowledge of Markdown. And `include` is a docutils specific feature. So once Sphinx determines that a given file is rst (rather than Markdown), that file is passed to Docutils as rst and the Markdown option no longer exists. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: Of course, Sphinx is mostly a wrapper which adds (and overrides) many of docutils' directives. So it may seem reasonable to expect that Sphinx could provide an `include` directive which was knowledgeable of Markdown. However, IIRC the `include` directive includes the *unprocessed* text which is parsed in a later step. That doesn't really work if the included document uses a different markup language.

Comment: @StevePiercy It renders as unprocessed text. It does throw Warning messages about the text, e.g. `../tutorial.md:49: WARNING: Unexpected indentation.`
I did install and configure my docs to use markdown with `recommonmark`; everything works perfect if I  use solely a `.md` file.



@Waylan
Unfortunately, that's along the lines of what I figured. I suppose such behavior could make things quite convoluted anyways. Thanks for the helpful information!

Comment: The warning indicates that Sphinx was trying to interpret the markdown syntax as reStructuredText syntax, as I can't recall off the top of my head any indentation used in markdown. As such, what @Waylan wrote about the context of the calling file sounds reasonable to me. I figured as much, too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### NOTE

The `mr2` extension seems to be abandoned. You can use the actively-maintained fork [m2r2](https://github.com/crossnox/m2r2) instead.

### Original Answer:

Try [M2R](https://github.com/miyakogi/m2r) sphinx extension.

https://github.com/miyakogi/m2r#sphinx-integration

After install m2r and change conf.py, just change `.. include` to `.. mdinclude` would work well.

```
ml
==

Tutorial
--------
.. mdinclude:: ../tutorial.md

w2v
^^^

.. automodule:: package.ml.w2v
:members:
```

Comment: Very useful answer, could be even quicker to use if `install m2r and change conf.py` were shown inside it. install is pip install and conf.py is about `extensions = ['m2r',  #... ]`

Comment: Wow. This worked for me. I am now self-hosting my documentation and this is the only thing that worked. I could not make recommonmark to work on my server.

Comment: This [doesn't seem to work anymore](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7420), since m2r is not actively maintained and [hasn't been updated to the newest sphinx api](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7420#issuecomment-609814898)

Comment: Seems to be working (again?) for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since release 0.19 (2022-06-21), Docutils' ["include" directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment) supports
a :parser: option that allows setting the parser for the included file to, e.g., myst, pycmark, or recommonmark.